# Is using “to a less extent” rather than “to a lesser extent” grammatically wrong today?

Tags: grammaticality, comparatives

The  expression [to a lesser extent](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/to-a-lesser-extent-degree) meaning  “less strongly or not so much” is commonly found with the comparative form of less.

Curiously, [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20a%20less%20extent%2Cto%20a%20lesser%20extent%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20a%20less%20extent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20a%20lesser%20extent%3B%2Cc0) shows that  “to a less extent” was initially, from the beginning of the 19c., the more common form and that only decades later the “lesser” form became the more commonly used.

Nowadays most dictionaries suggest the use of “lesser” as the correct one, but how did its usage evolve from less to lesser? Is “to a less extent” grammatically wrong?

Comment: *Is “to a less extent” grammatically wrong?* No. merely old-fashioned. The OED has it in notes as less as meaning "inferior" without any direct comparison being necessary. Lesser is a comparative and therefore does require a comparator. It seems the use of "less" became confused by the late 19th century as there was usually a comparator to be found.

Answer (score 2):

Johnson's 1755 dictionary [defines *lesser* as:](https://johnsonsdictionaryonline.com/views/search.php?term=lesser)

> A barbarous corruption of *less,* formed by the vulgar from the habit of terminating comparatives in *er*; afterwards adopted by poets, and then by writers of prose.

It seems that "lesser" was long considered incorrect, since it was the result of appending a comparative suffix to an adjective that was *already* comparative. Now, of course, it has taken over when used in this context.

Comment: Absolutely intriguing. What I like about this site is when I discover that my firm convictions of what is “correct” English turn out just to be current usage. On reflection, I wonder whether before using “to a lesser extent” I should ask myself whether I could express the idea in fewer words.